# Elements are shifting

Tags: html, css

I have this code:

```css
figure {
  background-color: #FFFFFF;
  text-align: center;
}

figcaption {
  font-style: italic;
  font-weight: bold;
}

figure em {
  font-weight: bold;
}

figure:hover,
figure:focus {
  background-color: rgba(255, 224, 224, 0.5);
  border: 15px inset #CCCCCC;
}
```

```html
<figure>
  <figcaption>Indesit IWSND</figcaption>
  <img src="obrazky/indesit-IWSND.jpg" width="220" height="220" alt="Indesit">
  <p>6 kg, 1200 ot/min.,A++</p>
  <p><em>229.00 &euro;</em></p>
</figure>
<figure>
  <figcaption>Rowenta RO5396OA</figcaption>
  <img src="obrazky/rowenta-RO5396OA.jpg" width="220" height="220" alt="Rowenta">
  <p>1,5 L, B, 950 watt</p>
  <p><em>108.00 &euro;</em></p>
</figure>
<figure>
  <figcaption>ETA 050490000</figcaption>
  <img src="obrazky/eta-05049000.jpg" width="220" height="220" alt="ETA">
  <p>O10 meter, 350 watt, C</p>
  <p><em>79.90 &euro;</em></p>
</figure>
```

And my problem is that when I move a mouse on those elements they shift a bit. How can I remove shifting of them?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your border is adding `15px` on each side, thus shifting the contents of the `<figure>`.

If your `<figure>` elements *started* with `15px` of padding (by doing `padding: 15px`), you could then replace that padding with your `15px` inset border on hover to keep the content in-place.

```css
figure {
  background-color: #FFFFFF;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 15px;    /* Start with 15px of padding */
}

figcaption {
  font-style: italic;
  font-weight: bold;
}

figure em {
  font-weight: bold;
}

figure:hover,
figure:focus {
  background-color: rgba(255, 224, 224, 0.5);
  border: 15px inset #CCCCCC;
  padding: 0px;  /* Replace padding with border */
}
```

```html
<figure>
  <figcaption>Indesit IWSND</figcaption>
  <img src="obrazky/indesit-IWSND.jpg" width="220" height="220" alt="Indesit">
  <p>6 kg, 1200 ot/min.,A++</p>
  <p><em>229.00 &euro;</em></p>
</figure>
<figure>
  <figcaption>Rowenta RO5396OA</figcaption>
  <img src="obrazky/rowenta-RO5396OA.jpg" width="220" height="220" alt="Rowenta">
  <p>1,5 L, B, 950 watt</p>
  <p><em>108.00 &euro;</em></p>
</figure>
<figure>
  <figcaption>ETA 050490000</figcaption>
  <img src="obrazky/eta-05049000.jpg" width="220" height="220" alt="ETA">
  <p>O10 meter, 350 watt, C</p>
  <p><em>79.90 &euro;</em></p>
</figure>
```

Answer (score 0):

The shift you are seeing is a result of going from no border to a 15px border (which shifts the area 15px). The easiest way to fix this would be to add a white border to the `.figure` style. It's there, but you won't notice it. When the hover/focus styles are displayed, the location of the `.figure` should stay right where it was.

```
figure {
   background-color: #FFFFFF;
   text-align: center;
   border: 15px inset #FFFFFF;
}

figure:hover, figure:focus  {
  background-color: rgba(255, 224, 224, 0.5);
  border: 15px inset #CCCCCC;
}
```

Comment: This is a good technique, but may I suggest doing `border: 15px inset transparent` instead of white. Using white will only work on a white background, whereas `transparent` (or, even an `rgba(...)` with `0` alpha) would work on *any* background.

Answer (score 0):

Solution: added "border: 15px solid #fff;" on figure normal state.

```css
figure {
  background-color: #FFFFFF;
  text-align: center;
  border: 15px solid #fff;
}

figcaption {
  font-style: italic;
  font-weight: bold;
}

figure em {
  font-weight: bold;
}

figure:hover,
figure:focus {
  background-color: rgba(255, 224, 224, 0.5);
  border: 15px inset #CCCCCC;
}
```

```html
<figure>
  <figcaption>Indesit IWSND</figcaption>
  <img src="obrazky/indesit-IWSND.jpg" width="220" height="220" alt="Indesit">
  <p>6 kg, 1200 ot/min.,A++</p>
  <p><em>229.00 &euro;</em></p>
</figure>
<figure>
  <figcaption>Rowenta RO5396OA</figcaption>
  <img src="obrazky/rowenta-RO5396OA.jpg" width="220" height="220" alt="Rowenta">
  <p>1,5 L, B, 950 watt</p>
  <p><em>108.00 &euro;</em></p>
</figure>
<figure>
  <figcaption>ETA 050490000</figcaption>
  <img src="obrazky/eta-05049000.jpg" width="220" height="220" alt="ETA">
  <p>O10 meter, 350 watt, C</p>
  <p><em>79.90 &euro;</em></p>
</figure>
```

Answer (score -1):

I think the only solution you can do is setting height for figure tag, like this

```css
figure {
 background-color: #FFFFFF;
 text-align: center;
  height: 150px;
}

figcaption {
 font-style: italic;
 font-weight: bold;  
}

figure em {
 font-weight: bold;
}   


figure:hover, figure:focus  {
background-color: rgba(255, 224, 224, 0.5);
border: 15px inset #CCCCCC;
}
```

```html
<figure>
 <figcaption>Indesit IWSND</figcaption>
 <img src="obrazky/indesit-IWSND.jpg" width="220" height="220" alt="Indesit">
 <p>6 kg, 1200 ot/min.,A++</p>
 <p><em>229.00 &euro;</em></p>
</figure>
<figure>
 <figcaption>Rowenta RO5396OA</figcaption>
 <img src="obrazky/rowenta-RO5396OA.jpg" width="220" height="220" alt="Rowenta">
 <p>1,5 L, B, 950 watt</p>
 <p><em>108.00 &euro;</em></p>
</figure>
<figure>
 <figcaption>ETA 050490000</figcaption>
 <img src="obrazky/eta-05049000.jpg" width="220" height="220" alt="ETA">
 <p>O10 meter, 350 watt, C</p>
 <p><em>79.90 &euro;</em></p>
</figure>
```